# How to select representative/prototypical images?

Tags: image, machine-learning, select, classification, supervised-learning

In the machine learning field, Semi-supervised learning is one of the main area researchers are working on. But the problem is, the accuracy(or any other metrics) is strongly depends on the randomly chosen labeled data. So I'd like to know how to select "representative" data from unlabeled dataset. It would be unsupervised learning technique and be data-agnostic. Here, "Data-agnostic" means a model chooses prototypical images with no regards to the datasets such as CIFAR10, 100, SVHN, MNIST or so on.

How would you make a model of this? If there are some papers about this topic, then please share this below. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Share my penny of thoughts on this. Taking the celebrity dataset as an example.

1. Apply PCA on the entire data to find out eigenfaces
2. Choose top 30 (arbitrary) eigenfaces to reconstruct all images
3. Select out those images with the lowest reconstruction error

because they are relatively easy to be represented by eigenfaces and thus more representative.

Comment: This is really helpful. But it depends on what error I use. What are the reconstruction errors? pix2pix MSE or Cross Entropy Loss? Are there any others?

Comment: I think the most common error is pixel-wise MSE, which is usually good enough.